# JOINing two sub-queries with calculated fields

Tags: sql, ms-access-2016

I have two tables containing info about the production of two widgets.  `Table1` looks like this:

[image: c]

Table2 looks like this:

[image]

I want to calculate the average production of each widget and display by the country code (ADM0_A3), so that the results would look something like this (not that bothered about missing data at this stage eg. BWA has no production of widget1)

```
ADM0_A3   w1avg   w2avg
DZA      50000  3450000
AGO      86000    40000
BWA      blank        0
CMR       3500    blank
```

The MS ACCESS SQL query I am using is here:

```
SELECT Z.ccode, Z.ave_w1, A.ave_w2 
FROM 
(
    SELECT X.ADM0_A3 as ccode, 0.02 * X.sum_w1 / X.n_w1 AS ave_w1 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT t1.ADM0_A3, SUM(t1.production) AS sum_w1, COUNT(t1.production) as n_w1 
        FROM Table1 t1
        GROUP BY t1.ADM0_A3
    ) X
) Z
JOIN
( 
    SELECT Y.ADM0_A3, 0.025 * Y.sum_w2 / Y.n_w2 AS ave_w2
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT t2.ADM0_A3, SUM(t2.production) AS sum_w2, COUNT(t2.production) as n_w2 
        FROM Table2 t2
        GROUP BY t2.ADM0_A3
    ) Y
) A
ON A.ADM0_A3 = Z.ccode
```

I checked the sub-queries and they work OK.  However, when I try to JOIN the queries I get this error message `"Syntax error in FROM clause"`.  I think the solution is something fairly simple but I just can't see it so would appreciate any suggestions.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: The second sub-query needs a name, just like Z for the first one..

Comment: Isn't it called Y?

Comment: poor data-structuire! should be one table with additional field widgetnr. You can crete actual strucure by a query filtering on that nr. That allows unlimited widgets, without creating new tables

Comment: No, it's unnamed. Compare X/Z.

Comment: Have updated the SQL query so that (I think) there is consistency between X/Z and Y/A ... but still get the synatax error

Comment: Imported the data into MySQL and the query works fine so seems to be an issue with ACCESS.  BTW what I needed with this query was FULL OUTER JOIN which is not available in MySQL or MS ACCESS - Gordon's solution using UNION ALL was much neater

Comment: ComputerVersteher - data structure shown is a simplified version of the actual structure to illustrate the problem.  Each widget has its own set of characteristics (some shared) which would give lots of NULL fields in a single table and require the table to be redesigned when a new widget is added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing this:

```
SELECT adm0_a3, MAX(w1avg) as w1avg, MAX(w2avg) as w2avg
FROM (SELECT t1.ADM0_A3, AVG(t1.production) * 0.02 as w1avg, NULL as w2avg
      FROM Table1 as t1
      GROUP BY t1.ADM0_A3
      UNION ALL
      SELECT t2.ADM0_A3, NULL, AVG(t2.production) * 0.02 as w1avg
      FROM Table1 as t2
      GROUP BY t2.ADM0_A3
     ) as t
GROUP BY adm0_a3;
```

I'm not sure if all versions of MS Access support `UNION ALL` in the `FROM` clause.  If not, you can work around that using a view.

Comment: Thanks Gordon - that worked!  I needed to change the first line to
SELECT adm0_a3, MAX(w1avg) as w1avgx, MAX(w2avg) as w2avgx
to avoid problems with circular references.  The use of MAX to eliminate empty/zero values is also neat!